# dpkg reports problems configuring huge list of python-related packages after any APT command

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, 13.10

I am having trouble installing any new packages in Ubuntu because of python.

I tried `sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev`  but I am getting the following output:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
python3 is already the newest version.
python3-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
280 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,207 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: error processing python-lockfile (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of duplicity:
 duplicity depends on python-lockfile; however:
  Package python-lockfile is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing duplicity (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of deja-dup:
 deja-dup depends on duplicity (>= 0.6.21); however:
  Package duplicity is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing deja-dup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing python-gi (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: error processing python-apt (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Setting up python-six (1.3.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-six (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: error processing python-chardet (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-debian:
 python-debian depends on python-six; however:
  Package python-six is not configured yet.
 python-debian depends on python-chardet; however:
  Package python-chardet is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-debian (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier-common:
 update-notifier-common depends on python-apt (>= 0.6.12); however:
  Package python-apt is not configured yet.
 update-notifier-common depends on python-debian; however:
  Package python-debian is not configured yet.`

dpkg: error processing update-notifier-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-sip (4.15.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-sip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-qt4:
 python-qt4 depends on sip-api-10.1; however:
  Package sip-api-10.1 is not installed.
  Package python-sip which provides sip-api-10.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-qt4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing python-dbus (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-qt4-dbus:
 python-qt4-dbus depends on python-dbus (>= 0.84.0-2~); however:
  Package python-dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-qt4-dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing python-dirspec (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: error processing python-httplib2 (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: error processing python-crypto (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-oauthlib:
 python-oauthlib depends on python-crypto; however:
  Package python-crypto is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-oauthlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-openssl (0.13-2ubuntu4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-openssl (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pkg-resources (0.6.37-1ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-pkg-resources (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-zope.interface:
 python-zope.interface depends on python-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python-pkg-resources is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-zope.interface (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-twisted-core:
 python-twisted-core depends on python-zope.interface (>= 3.6); however:
  Package python-zope.interface is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-twisted-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-twisted-web:
 python-twisted-web depends on python-twisted-core (>= 13.0); however:
  Package python-twisted-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-twisted-web (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-ubuntu-sso-client:
 python-ubuntu-sso-client depends on python-dbus; however:
  Package python-dbus is not configured yet.
 python-ubuntu-sso-client depends on python-dirspec; however:
  Package python-dirspec is not configured yet.
 python-ubuntu-sso-client depends on python-httplib2 (>= 0.7.2); however:
  Package python-httplib2 is not configured yet.
 python-ubuntu-sso-client depends on python-oauthlib (>= 0.3.5); however:
  Package python-oauthlib is not configured yet.
 python-ubuntu-sso-client depends on python-openssl; however:
  Package python-openssl is not configured yet.
 python-ubuntu-sso-client depends on python-twisted-core; however:
  Package python-twisted-core is not configured yet.
 python-ubuntu-sso-client depends on python-twisted-web; however:
  Package python-twisted-web is not configured yet.
 python-ubuntu-sso-client depends on python-zope.interface; however:
  Package python-zope.interface is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-ubuntu-sso-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-sso-client:
 ubuntu-sso-client depends on python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 13.10-0ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package python-ubuntu-sso-client is not configured yet. 

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-sso-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-sso-client-qt:
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt depends on python-qt4; however:
  Package python-qt4 is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt depends on python-qt4-dbus; however:
  Package python-qt4-dbus is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt depends on python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 13.10-0ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package python-ubuntu-sso-client is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt depends on ubuntu-sso-client (= 13.10-0ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package ubuntu-sso-client is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-sso-client-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-problem-report (2.12.5-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-problem-report (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: error processing python-keyring (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-lazr.uri:
 python-lazr.uri depends on python-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python-pkg-resources is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-lazr.uri (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-simplejson (3.3.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-simplejson (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-wadllib:
 python-wadllib depends on python-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python-pkg-resources is not configured yet.
 python-wadllib depends on python-lazr.uri; however:
  Package python-lazr.uri is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-wadllib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-oauth (1.0.1-3build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-oauth (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-lazr.restfulclient:
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-httplib2; however:
  Package python-httplib2 is not configured yet.
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-lazr.uri; however:
  Package python-lazr.uri is not configured yet.
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python-pkg-resources is not configured yet.
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-simplejson; however:
  Package python-simplejson is not configured yet.
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-wadllib (>= 1.1.4); however:
  Package python-wadllib is not configured yet.
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-zope.interface; however:
  Package python-zope.interface is not configured yet.
 python-lazr.restfulclient depends on python-oauth; however:
  Package python-oauth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-lazr.restfulclient (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-launchpadlib:
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-httplib2 (>= 0.4.0); however:
  Package python-httplib2 is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-keyring (>= 0.5); however:
  Package python-keyring is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-lazr.restfulclient (>= 0.11.2); however:
  Package python-lazr.restfulclient is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-lazr.uri (>= 1.0.2-4~); however:
  Package python-lazr.uri is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-oauth; however:
  Package python-oauth is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-simplejson; however:
  Package python-simplejson is not configured yet.
 python-launchpadlib depends on python-wadllib; however:
  Package python-wadllib is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-launchpadlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-apport:
 python-apport depends on python-apt (>= 0.7.9); however:
  Package python-apt is not configured yet.
 python-apport depends on python-problem-report (>= 0.94); however:
  Package python-problem-report is not configured yet.
 python-apport depends on python-launchpadlib (>= 1.5.7); however:
  Package python-launchpadlib is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distupgrade:
 python3-distupgrade depends on python-apport; however:
  Package python-apport is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-update-manager:
 python3-update-manager depends on python3-distupgrade; however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:0.205.6); however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager-core:
 update-manager-core depends on python3-update-manager (= 1:0.194.1); however:
  Package python3-update-manager is not configured yet.
 update-manager-core depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-core; however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing update-manager-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu1) ...

(gconftool-2:20627): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/gconf-schemas", line 121, in <module>
    trim(os.path.join(defaults_dest,"%gconf-tree.xml"), get_valid_languages())
  File "/usr/sbin/gconf-schemas", line 18, in get_valid_languages
    langs.add(l.split('_')[0])
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
dpkg: error processing gconf2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aisleriot:
 aisleriot depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing aisleriot (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-terminal-data:
 gnome-terminal-data depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing gnome-terminal-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-terminal:
 gnome-terminal depends on gnome-terminal-data (>= 3.6); however:
  Package gnome-terminal-data is not configured yet.
 gnome-terminal depends on gnome-terminal-data (<< 3.7); however:
  Package gnome-terminal-data is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing gnome-terminal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-xapian (1.2.15-4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-xapian (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt-xapian-index:
 apt-xapian-index depends on python-xapian (>= 1.0.2); however:
  Package python-xapian is not configured yet.
 apt-xapian-index depends on python-apt (>= 0.7.93.2); however:
  Package python-apt is not configured yet.
 apt-xapian-index depends on python-debian (>= 0.1.14); however:
  Package python-debian is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing apt-xapian-index (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apturl-common:
 apturl-common depends on python3-update-manager; however:
  Package python3-update-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing apturl-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apturl:
 apturl depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.
 apturl depends on apturl-common (= 0.5.2ubuntu2); however:
  Package apturl-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing apturl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of compiz-gnome:
 compiz-gnome depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing compiz-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of compiz:
 compiz depends on compiz-gnome; however:
  Package compiz-gnome is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing compiz (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of deja-dup-backend-gvfs:
 deja-dup-backend-gvfs depends on deja-dup; however:
  Package deja-dup is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing deja-dup-backend-gvfs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-xdg (0.25-3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-xdg (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-configglue:
 python-configglue depends on python-xdg; however:
  Package python-xdg is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-configglue (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-lockfile
 duplicity
 deja-dup
 python-gi
 python-apt
 python-six
 python-chardet
 python-debian
 update-notifier-common
 python-sip
 python-qt4
 python-dbus
 python-qt4-dbus
 python-dirspec
 python-httplib2
 python-crypto
 python-oauthlib
 python-openssl
 python-pkg-resources
 python-zope.interface
 python-twisted-core
 python-twisted-web
 python-ubuntu-sso-client
 ubuntu-sso-client
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt
 python-problem-report
 python-keyring
 python-lazr.uri
 python-simplejson
 python-wadllib
 python-oauth
 python-lazr.restfulclient
 python-launchpadlib
 python-apport
 python3-distupgrade
 python3-update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 update-manager-core
 gconf2
 aisleriot
 gnome-terminal-data
 gnome-terminal
 python-xapian
 apt-xapian-index
 apturl-common
 apturl
 compiz-gnome
 compiz
 deja-dup-backend-gvfs
 python-xdg
 python-configglue
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f`  but my output is:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
280 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,207 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing python-lockfile (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of duplicity:
 duplicity depends on python-lockfile; however:
  Package python-lockfile is not configured yet.`
```

Followed by same error as above.

I am using python 2.7.5. I have done `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean` and all variations on that theme.

I really want to be able to install `python-dev`. How can I make this happen?

Output for `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-lockfile`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
280 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,207 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 209306 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace python-lockfile 1:0.8-2ubuntu1 (using .../python-lockfile_1%3a0.8-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-lockfile_1%3a0.8-2ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-lockfile_1%3a0.8-2ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output for `apt-cache policy python-lockfile`

```
python-lockfile:
  Installed: 1:0.8-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:0.8-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:0.8-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output for `apt-cache policy python-minimal`

```
python-minimal:
  Installed: 2.7.5-5ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.7.5-5ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.5-5ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output for `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal python-lockfile`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
280 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 31.4 kB/5,238 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main python-minimal amd64 2.7.5-5ubuntu1 [31.4 kB]
Fetched 31.4 kB in 0s (93.3 kB/s)         
(Reading database ... 209306 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace python-lockfile 1:0.8-2ubuntu1 (using .../python-lockfile_1%3a0.8-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-lockfile_1%3a0.8-2ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to replace python-minimal 2.7.5-5ubuntu1 (using .../python-minimal_2.7.5-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement python-minimal ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-lockfile_1%3a0.8-2ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Tried -> _sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-lockfile_

Comment: [The answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/534047/22949) apparently applies to later releases and [has been helping people with them](https://askubuntu.com/a/883334/22949), so this appears not to be EoL-specific after all. I'm voting to reopen this. (It also seems likely that this problem would have to have been solved in order to effect an upgrade, so in hindsight it probably didn't make very much sense for us to close it originally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was updating python in `/usr/local/bin`,
but the actual installation is in `/usr/bin/`.

Answer (score 25):

the root cause of your apt problems is `python-lockfile`, try to reinstall it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal python-lockfile
```

EDIT:

You're running 13.10 (which reached its EOL), please update your repositories to install from old-releases.ubuntu.com, see [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release).

You could also try to manually remove `python-lockfile_1%3a0.8-2ubuntu1_all.deb` from the cache and retry the above commands:

```
sudo rm "/var/cache/apt/archives/python-lockfile_1%3a0.8-2ubuntu1_all.deb"
```

Comment: Please comment on my answer, leave comments on your question for people who ask for more details

Comment: I did try the suggestions and displayed the results in the question. But, the problem is not yet solved.

Comment: I use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal python-lockfile`.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is something about python3-cursesmenu such that `sudo apt-get install ...` does not work well. `sudo -H apt-get install ...` resolves the issue.