# Error importing lxml package python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, lxml

When I try importing lxml package in python I am receiving the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in    <module>
   from lxml import etree
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol:   PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeLatin1
```

Please help to fix this.
(Python version ->2.7.5)

Comment: Check out this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806831/ubuntu-11-04-lxml-import-etree-problem-for-custom-python#), it might help. My guess is that the package you get from apt doesn't supposrt the UCS4 and you may need to build from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/534460/32239) to a different question, you have a python interpreter in `/usr/local/bin`.

As [musher](https://askubuntu.com/users/284690/musher) pointed out it could not have been compiled to support ucs4. Try with the version installed in `/usr/bin` instead.