# Problems after installing Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 completely now on my machine aswell as the newest Python version (3.5.1).
now i have problems with following packages:

> ```
> python-cairo
> python-gobject-2
> python-pip
> python-pkg-resources
> python-wheel
> ```
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

```
me@me-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libexpat1-dev libldb1 libpython-all-dev
  libpython-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libtalloc2 libtevent0
  libwbclient0 python2.7-dev
Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
5 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
python-cairo (1.8.8-2) wird eingerichtet ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes python-cairo (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-12ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes python-gobject-2 (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
python-pip (8.1.1-2) wird eingerichtet ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes python-pip (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
python-pkg-resources (20.7.0-1) wird eingerichtet ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes python-pkg-resources (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da das Limit MaxReports bereits erreicht ist.
    python-wheel (0.29.0-1) wird eingerichtet ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes python-wheel (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da das Limit MaxReports bereits erreicht ist.
    Trigger für libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) werden verarbeitet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 python-cairo
 python-gobject-2
 python-pip
 python-pkg-resources
 python-wheel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you please run `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt-get install -f` and include the output here? That way we would see the English error messages.

Comment: same problem, here's solution - http://askubuntu.com/a/534047/536939